# activeMQ multiple consumer issue

Tags: glassfish, activemq-classic

We have two instances of activemq configured as a cluster and a cluster of four glassfish instances, that should be connected to ONE activemq at any given time. If activemq01 is unavailable, all four glassfish instances should failover on activemq02.

I've noticed several times, that for unknown reason, one of (random) glassfish instances will failover on activemq02, and remaining three instances will still be connected to activemq01, even though activemq01 was NOT down, and all glassfish instances should have been listening on activemq01.

Logs don't indicate anything that would explain this behavior, all I can see if that one glassfish instance couldn't connect to activemq01 and failedover on activemq02.

Have anybody experienced the same or similar issues? Any help/advise is greatly appreciated.

Here are my activemq configs :

activemq01 :

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd 
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties

```
<managementContext>
  <managementContext connectorPort="1093" createConnector="true"/>
</managementContext>

<networkConnectors>
  <networkConnector name="amq-prod" uri="static://(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616,tcp://192.168.0.167:61616)" />
</networkConnectors>


<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>

<plugins>
  <loggingBrokerPlugin logAll="false" logConnectionEvents="true"/>
</plugins>


<systemUsage>
  <systemUsage>
    <memoryUsage>
      <memoryUsage limit="2048 mb"/>
    </memoryUsage>
    <storeUsage>
      <storeUsage limit="2 gb" name="prod"/>
    </storeUsage>
    <tempUsage>
      <tempUsage limit="2000 mb"/>
    </tempUsage>
  </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>

<transportConnectors>
  <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" updateClusterClients="true" />
</transportConnectors>
```

#

activeMQ02:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd 
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties

```
<managementContext>
  <managementContext connectorPort="1093" createConnector="true"/>
</managementContext>

<networkConnectors>
  <networkConnector name="amq-prod" uri="static://(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616,tcp://192.168.0.166:61616)"  />
</networkConnectors>


<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

```
<systemUsage>
  <systemUsage>
    <memoryUsage>
      <memoryUsage limit="2048 mb"/>
    </memoryUsage>
    <storeUsage>
      <storeUsage limit="2 gb" name="prod"/>
    </storeUsage>
    <tempUsage>
      <tempUsage limit="2000 mb"/>
    </tempUsage>
  </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>

<transportConnectors>
  <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" updateClusterClients="true" />
</transportConnectors>
```

version of activeMQ - 5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your networkConnector tag defined like this:

**acticemq01 config:**

```
 <networkConnector
         name="amq1-nc" 
         uri="static:(failover:(tcp://192.168.0.167:61616))" 
         networkTTL="2" 
         duplex="true"
         dynamicOnly="true" 
  />
```

**acticemq02 config:**

```
 <networkConnector
         name="amq2-nc" 
         uri="static:(failover:(tcp://192.168.0.166:61616))" 
         networkTTL="2" 
         duplex="true"
         dynamicOnly="true" 
  />
```

And in your consumers use **JMS provider URL** like this:

```
failover:(tcp://192.168.0.166:61616,tcp://192.168.0.167:61616)?randomize=false&timeout=5000
```

Above [failover](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) URL will always connect to acticemq01 broker if it is available. If acticemq01 goes down it will automatically failover to acticemq02 broker. Also timeout=5000 will make sure that consumer throws back error in 5 sec in an attempt to connect to any of the 2 brokers.

Comment: Thank you Anubhava! The issue with this configuration is, that when I stop activemq01, the connections fail on activemq02, but when I tried starting activemq01 back, and stopped activemq02, the consumers didn't fail back over to activemq01.

Comment: my pending queue is keep stacking up, and I've spend a lot of time researching and tweaking the settings, and not sure what's going on. This is happening ONLY with one of the queues. Just to give you some inside, in case you can advise on improving the performance by some configuration changes :

Comment: the producer puts message objects in the queue, which has several dozens of individual contacts, then the consumers (4) listening on that queue, and pick the message (object), parse and deliver to a remove vendor, one contact at the time. It's know that the performance of the vendor delivery is slow, do you think if I increase the prefetch size on that queue (currently is 100), it will correct the issue and messages will not stack up in the pending queue?  Thank you in advance

Comment: It is advisable that if you know a particular consumer is going to be slow then set its prefetch size to something smaller. For your particular of handling large pending messages I would suggest you to look at this page: http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

Comment: Here is the process: a single message in the queue may contain 100 contacts, so one of the glassfish instances will pickup the message from the queue, then parse the object message and send each contact individually, which takes about 4 minutes. My understanding is that since activemq is expecting an acknowledgement sooner than 4 minutes, it marks them as "redeliver" and puts in the pending queue. Is there a way to increase that timing in activemq for that particular queue so it waits about 4 minutes for an acks/nacks? or even don't wait for acknowledgement at all, just fire and forget?

Comment: ACK is sent immediately as the message is received on consumers, it is not held up for further processing on consumer. How many concurrent consumer threads you are creating per consumer instance? I would creating 16 per instance. For my Spring message listener container I sue ` <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="16" />` for this. But for producers you can of course use `jms.useAsyncSend=true` at the end of JMS provider URL to make sending asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. I'm checking via jconsole and max concurrent connections that I can see per glassfish instance is 6, however each glassfish instance can go up to 32. I've tried using "<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="16" />", but that didn't work, activemq won't even start with that property.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd 
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

Comment: <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="16" />
  </bean>

Comment: Sorry `<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="16" />` is not to be used in AMQ config. It is used in **Spring message listener container** to set concurrent # of listeners for each consumer instance. If your consumers are very slow taking a lot of time, you will see pending messages on ActiveMQ broker, that's an expected behavior. eg: if each consumer instance can go up to 32 then you can concurrently process 32x3=128 messages and since each message is taking upto 4 min, all the messages arriving meanwhile go in pending state.